# Где ошибка, вместо решения выдает NaN. Задача: через функции найти делители числа и найти их сумму

Tags: javascript

```js
function getOwnDivisors(num) {
  let arr = [];
  for (i = 1; i < num; i++) {
    if (num % i == 0) {
      arr[i] = i;
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

function getSum(arr) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let elem of arr) {
    sum = sum + elem;
  }
  return sum;
}


console.log(getSum(getOwnDivisors(121)));
```

Comment: Вы пытаетесь сложить числа с undefined в функции getSum. А undefined у вас в массиве т.к вы добавляете элементы в массив по индексу. Если добавить в пустой массив ЧТО-ТО на 10 индекс, то все 9 предыдущих станут undefined, добавляйте через push и все будет хорошо

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getOwnDivisors(num) {
  let arr = [];
  for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    // Если не подходит по условию  просто подставляем 0
    // Потому что если прибавить 0 сумма не изменится
    arr[i] = num % i == 0 ? i : 0
  }
  return arr;
}

function getSum(arr) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let elem of arr) {
    sum += elem;
  }
  return sum;
}


console.log(getSum(getOwnDivisors(121)));
```

А вообще все это можно сделать проще

```js
function summ(num){
  return Array
    .apply(null, {length: num}) // создаем пустой массив
    .map(Number.call, Number)   // забиваем последовательными данными
    .filter((f,ind) => {        // отбираем только то что нам нужно
      return num % ind == 0
    })
    .reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr) // складываем
}

const res = summ(121)
console.log(res)
```